# PowerShell Remoting Sporadic Script Exiting

Tags: powershell, amazon-s3, powershell-remoting

I have a script that executes an `aws s3 sync`, which should sync approx 255GB. However, the script seems to choke up at random points and exit with:

```
[13:49:24][Step 1/1] Processing data for a remote command failed with the following error message: 
[13:49:24][Step 1/1] Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting 
[13:49:24][Step 1/1] Help topic.
[13:49:24][Step 1/1]     + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (fileserver:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
[13:49:24][Step 1/1]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : JobFailure
[13:49:24][Step 1/1]     + PSComputerName        : fileserver
[13:49:24][Step 1/1]
```

This error occurs after varying amounts of time, and varying amounts of data pulled down from S3. There doesn't seem to be a common denominator for when its dying. Another important fact is that the script is being executed by TeamCity, so it's logging in from TC as an admin on the remote server.

Any ideas on why this is occurring?

Comment: Did you check the eventlogs (local and remote) for more information?

Comment: Can you give us any more details about the sync? Possible that you may need to throttle the sync, see this question for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30620402/775544